# Rails - RoutingError on precompiled asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-routing, sprockets

I'm still learning Rails so sorry if this question sounds amateurish. I'm running Rails on a Ubuntu VM, Passenger + Nginx. I've run `asset:precompile` and it seems to succeed without error. However when I boot up my server in production environment and try to visit the page, I get

```
[INFO ] GET     "/images/pages/home/index/features/healthy_big.jpg"  for 202.189.127.97  at 2015-04-03 19:00:06 +0800
[FATAL]
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/pages/home/index/features/healthy_big.jpg"):
```

The file was compiled to `healthy_big-5fb165905a0d689780f44dbb9b178f00.jpg` in my `public/assets/pages/home/index/features/` directory.

The weird thing is that some other images, which are also hashed, are loaded perfectly without problem. For example the file `landing_1.jpg`, which became `landing_1-cd89a8ce37aab0ebffb9529b7ec430ae.jpg` within `public/assets/pages/home/index`, showed up perfectly. The way I tried to show these two images are both via `image_tag`:

`= image_tag("pages/home/index/features/healthy_big.jpg", alt: t('views.templates.home.index.img_alts.healthy'))`

`= image_tag('pages/home/index/landing_1.jpg')`

What could be the cause of the issue? I guess Rails should be automatically find the hashed asset, though the original name was requested? Or do I need to do a recompilation etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error. It's actually not anything related to asset pipeline! It's a caching issue. In the `desktop.html.haml` file, I used

```
- local_cache [:tour, :sub_section_1,
    :locale_2015_02_28_001,
    :assets_2015_02_28_001] do
```

for the divs containing the images. However I actually changed the asset image after Feb 28th. Therefore, an attempt was made to fetch the asset from cache of intermediate server (note that `202.189.127.97` is NOT my production server, but something I'm connected to using my development machine).

Changing the caching directives to

```
- local_cache [:tour, :sub_section_1,
    :locale_2015_02_28_001,
    :assets_2015_04_03_001] do
```

fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is because things work differently in development as compared to production.
Few thing to note:-

1. No CSS or JS files will be available to your app through the asset pipeline unless they are included in other files **OR** listed in the `config.precompile` directive. Only `application.css` and `application.js` are available by default of all the CSS and JS files.
2. Every file that is not a Javascript file or CSS file that is in the app/assets folder will be copied by **Rails** into the `public/assets` folder when you compile your assets. So if you want to add some web fonts, you could make an app/assets/fonts/ folder and put your fonts in there, these will then be copied to `public/assets/fonts` folder when you compile your assets. Note that your `app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.css.scss` file that references those fonts will **NOT** be copied over unless you either added it to the `config.assets.precompile` directive or required it from your `application.css`
3. for `config.assets.compile`...If it is set to "true" (which it is by default in development) then **Rails** will try to find a Javascript or CSS file by first looking in the `public/assets` directory and if it can't find it, will hunt through your `app/assets` folder looking for the file. If it finds it in `app/assets` it will go ahead and compile on the fly and then serve this asset up.

The problem with this is that you don't notice it happening in development, then you commit everything and push to production and BOOM, everything is broken with 500 errors because **production** has `config.assets.compile` set to "false"**. This prevents the app from "falling back" and trying to load the file directly instead of using the asset pipeline.**

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false
```

*Why don't you just have this set to "true" in every environment? Well, because it is sloooooow. And you don't want slow in production*

4. Run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile`
5. check public/assets directory and verify that assets are compiled..if its not empty...that means asset pipeline is working but path is not correct.use [asset_helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) to set the path of assets in css files.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. However I don't think that caused my the problem here. In fact even after I set config.assets.compile = true, the same error persisted, even though the file `healthy_big.jpg` are definitely there in `app/assets`. It must be something else that was wrong. Strange because it worked well in development. Could it be something related to passenger/nginx?